# Extending formatoptions in vim

Tags: vim

With my default settings, the`formatoptions` flag is `tcq` for text files, and `croql` for C++. I don't like that it autowraps the text, so I put this into my vimrc:

```
autocmd FileType text set formatoptions-=t
```

So far, this works as expected. Now I want to turn on comment joining on C++, so I add the following line to my vimrc just after the above line:

```
autocmd FileType c,cpp set formatoptions+=j
```

Now the `formatoptions` becomes `croqlj` for every file, not just C/C++, but also for text. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

`'formatoptions'` is a *buffer-local* option; you should use `:setlocal` instead of `:set`.

With the latter, you not only change the option for the current buffer, but also modify the global default for any future buffer that gets opened.